# Set-theory, functions between sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Check, if the following function, from set $A$ to $B$ are injective, surjective or bijective

$ A=\mathcal {P}(\omega),\ B=\omega\cup\{\omega\}\ and\ \forall x\in A:\ F_1(x)=\bigcup\{n\in\omega:n\subseteq x\}$

This function can't be injective i think because domain has a greater cardinality but what does $\ B=\omega\cup\{\omega\}$ mean ?

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions at once. This makes your question unlikely to be of help for future readers (who are unlikely to have trouble with precisely the same set of questions), and also harder to answer all of them in satisfying detail. You can [edit] your question to focus on one of the three functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct that it cannot be injective (so can't be bijective, either), and your reasoning is perfect. What this means is that $B$ is the set whose members are:

- the natural numbers $(0,1,2,3,4,...)$
- the set of natural numbers $(\omega).$

This function *does* turn out to be surjective. To see it, bear in mind that each element of $\omega$ is a subset of $\omega,$ as well (and of course, $\omega$ is a subset of itself).

(From your original post, $F_2$ is neither injective nor surjective. Your reasoning for why it wasn't surjective was fine. We could also use a cardinality argument such as that which you used to show that $F_1$ couldn't be injective. $F_0$, however, is the identity function on $\omega,$ so is both injective and surjective, given the domain and codomain.)

Answer (score 1):

$B$ is the set whose elements are the finite ordinals and the ordinal $\omega$:

$$B=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\cup\{\omega\}\;.$$

It is usually denoted by $\omega+1$: it’s the next ordinal after $\omega$.

$$F_1(\omega)=\bigcup\{n\in\omega:n\subseteq\omega\}=\omega\;,$$

so the codomain of $F_1$ has to include $\omega$ as an element. It also has to contain every finite ordinal, and nothing else is needed, so $B=\omega\cup\{\omega\}$ is the smallest possible codomain for $F_1$. If $S\subsetneqq\omega$, then

$$\begin{align*}
F_1(S)&=\bigcup\{n\in\omega:n\subseteq S\}\\
&=\bigcup\{n\in\omega:\forall k\in n(k\in S)\}\\
&=\bigcup\{n\in\omega:n\le m\}\\
&=m\;,
\end{align*}$$

where $m=\min(\omega\setminus S)$.

Comment: here you mean with $A$ an arbitrary set, not the power set, right ?

Comment: @derivative: An arbitrary proper subset of $\omega$. Sorry: I forgot that $A$ was already in use; I’ve changed it to $S$.